# Is dunn.test a suitable alternative to kruskalmc in pgirmess package?

Tags: r, nonparametric, cumulative-distribution-function, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I'm trying to run the krushkalmc method after running kruskal.test as part of my analysis with the Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test. I have data with a small sample size that also does not have a normal distribution so I thought that the Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test would be an appropriate choice.

My resulting p-value is .004 but I'd like to do a post-hoc test as well to understand which group(s) differ.

However, I've run into difficulties trying to install the pgirmess package that contains krushkalmc.

1. Trying to install it from inside R:

   install.packages("pgirmess")
      package ‘pgirmess’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
2. So then I downloaded it and tried to install it manually:

   install.packages("pgirmess", repos = NULL, type="source")
   Warning: invalid package ‘pgirmess’
   Error: ERROR: no packages specified
   Warning in install.packages :
     installation of package ‘pgirmess’ had non-zero exit status

and here is my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.8     grid_3.1.2      
 [4] gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.3     MASS_7.3-35     
 [7] munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10    
[10] Rcpp_0.11.4      reshape2_1.4.1   scales_0.2.4    
[13] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.2
```

I've tried to determine if any other package has the kruskalmc but don't see any.

So my questions are:

1. Do you have any recommendations for installing pgirmess?
2. Is dunn.test a suitable replacement for identifying which group(s) have significantly different scores? It also [notes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dunn.test/) that

> The interpretation of stochastic dominance requires an assumption that
>   the CDF of one group does not cross the CDF of the other

How do I determine if this CDF - cumulative distribution constraint is met?

Disclaimer: I first opened this question in stackoverflow but closed it there as I think this is a more appropriate site.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Questions about how to install software are off topic here. Please see our [list of resources on statistics software](meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software).  In any case, even if it were on topic, in general it is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your not-directly-related questions into one. If you edit to include only the question about post hoc tests, your question should be on topic.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to read the question [What is the difference between various Kruskal-Wallis post-hoc tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141856/what-is-the-difference-between-various-kruskal-wallis-post-hoc-tests/141872#141872) and my answer to it.

From that answer:

> `dunn.test` provides Dunn's (1964) *z* test approximation to a rank sum test employing both the same ranks used in the Kruskal-Wallis test, and the pooled variance estimate implied by the null hypothesis of the Kruskal-Wallis (akin to using the pooled variance to calculate *t* test statistics following an ANOVA).
>
> The `kruskalmc` function in the `pgirmess` package implements Dunn's *post hoc* rank sum comparison using *z* test statistics as directed by Siegel and Castellan (1988), but [these authors do not include Dunn's (1964) correction for ties](http://giraudoux.pagesperso-orange.fr/SiegelCastellan1988.pdf), so `kruskalmc` will be less accurate than `dunn.test` when ties exist in the data.

For your second question, you will want to read the question [Can a CDF from data cross with another CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128773/can-a-cdf-from-data-cross-with-another-cdf)? and its answer.

**References**

Dunn, O. J. (1964). Multiple comparisons using rank sums. *Technometrics*, 6(3):241–252.

Siegel and Castellan (1988) *Non parametric statistics for the behavioural sciences*. MacGraw Hill Int., New York. pp 213-214

Answer (score 0):

I think that Alexis recommendation of `dunn.test` is a better option, because the **ties correction** and also the `pgirmess` package have more dependencies especially `rgdal`.
`rgdal` requires `sp` and after installing it, you can install `pgirmess` .

Install `sp`:

```
install.packages('sp')
```

For Ubuntu install `gdal` and PROJ.4:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

In R now you can try :

```
install.packages('pgirmess')
```

In Mac:

```
install.packages(‘rgdal’,repos=”http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin“)
install.packages('pgirmess')
```

If in Mac this fails, there is a [Hard Way](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rgdal-on-a-mac/)