# What is the difference between various Kruskal-Wallis post-hoc tests?

Tags: r, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

[There seem to be a lot of similar questions here, so please point me the right direction if this has already been answered, but I *think* it's reasonably differentiated.]

There are many different implementations of post-hoc analyses following a Kruskal-Wallis test. I'm trying to understand how (why?) they differ, to get a sense of when one might be the right choice over another.

Working in R, consider this simulated dataset

```
generate.sim.data<-function(seed){
 set.seed(seed)
 sim1<-rnorm(20,4,3)
 sim2<-rnorm(20,7,3)
 sim3<-rnorm(20,1,3)
 sim4<-rnorm(20,1,3)
 simdata<-c(sim1,sim2,sim3,sim4)
 simgroup<-c(rep(c("sim1","sim2","sim3","sim4"),each=20))
 data.frame(simdata,simgroup)
}
```

The functions `kruskal` in the package `agricolae`; `kruskalmc` in the package `pgirmess`, `posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test` in the package `PMCMR`, and `dunn.test` in the package `dunn.test` all give different statistics (for any input). For certain values, they also give varying results in pairwise comparisons

```
  sim<-generate.sim.data(123)
  kruskal(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup,console=T)               #a,b,c,c
  kruskalmc(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)                       #a,a,b,b
  posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)    #a,a,b,b
  dunn.test(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)                       #a,b,c,c
```

but agree in some more clearcut cases:

```
  sim<-generate.sim.data(321)
  kruskal(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup,console=T)               #a,a,b,b
  kruskalmc(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)                       #a,a,b,b
  posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)    #a,a,b,b
  dunn.test(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)                       #a,a,b,b
```

It seems that `kruskalmc` and `posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test` give similar results no matter what, and `kruskal` and `dunn.test` tend to give similar results, but this latter is not always the case, e.g.

```
  sim<-generate.sim.data(4444)
  kruskal(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup,console=T)               #a,b,c,c
  kruskalmc(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)                       #ac,a,b,bc
  posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)    #ac,a,b,bc
  dunn.test(sim$simdata,sim$simgroup)                       #ac,b,c,c
```

I realize I'm quibbling about some different behavior of the tests based on p-values very close to 0.05, but these tests also do give different diagnoses for real data sets (e.g., `observation~method` from the `corn` data in `agricolae`; `occupation~eligibility` from the `homecare` data in `dunn.test`). I wondered what the underlying differences are between the tests, and whether there's a reasonable criterion to choose one over another.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Understanding *how* these test implementations differ requires understanding the actual test statistics themselves.

For example, [**`dunn.test`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dunn.test) provides Dunn's (1964) *z* test approximation to a rank sum test employing both the same ranks used in the Kruskal-Wallis test, and the pooled variance estimate implied by the null hypothesis of the Kruskal-Wallis (akin to using the pooled variance to calculate *t* test statistics following an ANOVA).

By contrast, the Kruskal-Nemenyi test as implemented in `posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test` is based on either the [Studentized range distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range), or the [$\chi^{2}$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) depending on user choice.

The `kruskalmc` function in the `pgirmess` package implements Dunn's *post hoc* rank sum comparison using *z* test statistics as directed by Siegel and Castellan (1988), but [these authors do not include Dunn's (1964) correction for ties](http://giraudoux.pagesperso-orange.fr/SiegelCastellan1988.pdf), so `kruskalmc` will be less accurate than [**`dunn.test`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dunn.test) when ties exist in the data.

It is difficult to discern from the documentation of `kruskal` whether the author is using the Conover-Iman *t* approximation to the distribution of rank sum differences (similar to Dunn's test, but requires that the Kruskal-Wallis be rejected, and is more powerful). A brief glance at the code does not immediately scream out *Conover-Iman* to me, however, it is quite possible that is an implementation of the test. More certainly implemented in R is the [**`conover.test`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=conover.test) package.

**The tl;dr: these all appear to be implementations of different test statistics or different forms of the same test statistic, so there is no reason to expect them to agree.**

**References**

W. Jay Conover (1999) *Practical Nonparametrics Statistics*.

Conover, W. J. and Iman, R. L. (1979). [On multiple-comparisons procedures](http://library.lanl.gov/cgi-bin/getfile?00209046.pdf). Technical Report LA-7677-MS, Los Alamos Scientific Laboratory.

Dunn, O. J. (1964). [Multiple comparisons using rank sums](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1266041). *Technometrics*, 6(3):241–252.

Siegel and Castellan (1988) *Non parametric statistics for the behavioural sciences*. MacGraw Hill Int., New York. pp 213-214

Comment: @SalMangiafico I am the author of dunn.test, and assure you that if you read the documentation, you will find that dunn.test performs two-sided tests (you are likely being bewildered by the mathematical equivalence of the rejection decision $p \leq\alpha/2$ vs. $2p \leq \alpha$). The documentation for dunn.test is explicit in its definition of rejection probabilities. Your opinion about output is, naturally, not being debated. Personally, *post-hoc* to rejecting a Kruskal-Wallis, I would recommend conover.test as the Conover-Iman test is strictly more powerful that Dunn's test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico His reports $p = P(|Z|  \ge |z|)$. Mine reports $p = P(Z \ge |z|)$. For the multiple comparisons adjustments procedures reporting significance, mine reject at (my) $p \le \alpha/2$, whereas his reject at (his) $p \le \alpha$. It's really pretty straightforward. (You may gather that his $p$ is twice my $p$.) Derek and I have already been in touch; he based his dunTest code on mine.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this thread is older, but I came across it because I was looking for answers about the post-hoc test applied to the Kruskal-Wallis test found in the `agricolae` package. I really needed to know for documentation purposes so I personally emailed the maintainer to ask what procedure is used for the post-hoc test. He told me that it does use a procedure from Conover. Here is his specific reply in reference to the Kruskal-Wallis post-hoc test:

> The Kruskal test is nonparametric, but it is feasible to apply a function as the least significant difference on mean ranks, which can make an adjustment on probability, the procedure is a criterion with the critical range by Conover.

I hope this helps to answer the question regarding the Kruskal-Wallis test in `agricolae`.

Comment: Conover's test is very powerful, but note that it can have inflated type I errors, so you want to mitigate against that. I have found that requiring a significant KW, then only comparing levels chosen a-priori w/ Bonferroni corrections does not yield type I error inflation & remains more powerful than other tests.

Comment: @gung Yes. Conover and Iman were explicit about the test being strictly applicable *pos hoc* to rejecting a KW.